# Let $\aleph_\alpha$ be a singular cardinal and $2^{\aleph_\xi}=\aleph_\beta$ for all $\xi<\alpha$. Then $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_\beta$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals

> Let $\aleph_\alpha$ be a singular cardinal. Let us assume that the value of $2^{\aleph_\xi}$ is the same for all $\xi<\alpha$, say $2^{\aleph_\xi}=\aleph_\beta$. Then $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_\beta$.

My textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech presents a proof as follows:

> [image]

1. I am unable to get $\color{blue}{\text{By the assumption, we have }2^{\kappa_i}=\aleph_\beta\text{ for all }i\in I}$.

In this proof, $\kappa_i<\aleph_\alpha$, but I do not see why $\kappa_i=\aleph_\xi$ for some $\xi<\alpha$. I think it is possible that $\kappa_i<\aleph_0$ for some $i\in I$ and thus $2^{\kappa_i}\neq 2^{\aleph_\xi}$ for all $\xi<\alpha$. In this case, we can not use the assumption as the authors did.

2. I am also unable to understand why the authors are sure that $\color{blue}{|I|=\aleph_\gamma}$. I can not rule out the possibility that $|I|\in\omega$.

Please elaborate on these points. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @WilliamElliot, I don't understand what you meant.

Comment: Let us assume that the value of $2^{\aleph_\xi}$ is the same for all $\xi<\alpha$,  How can such ever occure?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I guess that's why the authors said *Let us assume...* :)

Comment: Hi @bof, could you please more specific?

Comment: Hi @bof, i seem to get your point. $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=2^{\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i}=\prod_{i\in I}2^{\kappa_i}\le\prod_{i\in I}\aleph_\beta=\aleph_\beta^{\aleph_\gamma}=(2^{\aleph_\gamma})^{\aleph_\gamma}=2^{\aleph_\gamma}=\aleph_\beta$. In short, $2^{\aleph_\alpha} \le \aleph_\beta$. On the other hand, $2^{\aleph_\alpha} \ge 2^{\aleph_\xi}=\aleph_\beta$ for some $\xi<\alpha$. It follows that $2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \aleph_\beta$. But i have another confusion: how can the authors be sure that $\color{blue}{|I|=\aleph_\gamma}$. I can not rule out the possibility that $|I|\in\omega$.

Comment: @WilliamElliot It certainly *can* occur. Say if $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_\xi$ for all $\xi < \alpha$ and Martin's axiom holds, then $2^{\aleph_\xi} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ for all $\xi < \alpha.$

Comment: $|I|$ cannot be finite, because, if it were, the sum $\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i$ would be a finite sum, hence equal to the largest of the $\kappa_i$'s (or finite if all the $\kappa_i$'s are finite), and hence smaller than $\aleph_\alpha$, contrary to the choice of the $\kappa_i$'s as having sum equal to $\aleph_\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndreasBlass! I got it.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Easton's theorem allows us to consistently have a lot of maybe counterintuitive cardinal exponentation values..

Comment: @Henno: Actually Cohen already proved it in the first paper about CH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by disregarding any finite $\kappa_i$: they don't contribute to the sum anyway and $I$ only gets smaller, and also note that $I$ cannot be finite, or the sum would be the maximal element in the sum which is stricty less than $\aleph_\alpha$. This is always the case when writing a singular cardinal as a small sum of smaller elements. So $I$ is an infinite cardinal, and so are all $\kappa_i$ and so equal to alephs (under AC, which we are).

As $\kappa_i < \aleph_\alpha$ and so $\kappa_i = \aleph_\gamma$ for some $\gamma < \alpha$ (if $\gamma \ge \alpha$, we'd have $\kappa_i=\aleph_\gamma \ge \aleph_\alpha$, as $\gamma \to \aleph_\gamma$ is monotonous). And then it's an immediate application of the theorem's assumptions that $2^{\kappa_i} = \aleph_\beta$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I am clear.

Comment: Could you please check my approach in which I do not remove any finite $\kappa_i$ from the sum? We have $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=2^{\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i}=\color{blue}{\prod_{i\in I}2^{\kappa_i}\le\prod_{i\in I}\aleph_\beta}=\aleph_\beta^{\aleph_\gamma}=(2^{\aleph_\gamma})^{\aleph_\gamma}=2^{\aleph_\gamma}=\aleph_\beta$. In short, $2^{\aleph_\alpha} \le \aleph_\beta$. On the other hand, $2^{\aleph_\alpha} \ge 2^{\aleph_\xi}=\aleph_\beta$ for some $\xi<\alpha$. It follows that $2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \aleph_\beta$.

Comment: @LeAnhDung looks fine. But why prove two inequalities when one equality also works?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by *one equality also works*. To prove $2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \aleph_\beta$, I first prove $2^{\aleph_\alpha} \le \aleph_\beta$ and then $2^{\aleph_\alpha} \ge \aleph_\beta$.

Comment: @LeAnhDung Hrbaček and Jech give a proof with only equalities. That’s a fine proof.

Comment: Oh I got it now. Many thanks for you!

Comment: @LeAnhDung glad to help. Only summarised arguments also given in the comments.